# Date Stamping for multiple users (currently only working for owner of spreadsheet)

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am struggling with my script again. :( I'm trying to allow multiple people to edit my sheet but my Script is only working for owner and not users? I need it to edit column A with a date anytime ANYONE enters something in a specific column. The other accounts that are editing are using iPads if this changed anything. This is the code Im currently using:

```
function onEdit() {

var sheetNames = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3', 'Sheet4'];
var colsToCheck = [9, 10, 9, 9];
var colOffsets = [-8, -9, -8, -8];

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
var name = sheet.getSheetName();

var index = sheetNames.indexOf(name);

if (index > -1) { 
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var col = cell.getColumn();

  if (col == colsToCheck[index]) { 
      var dateTimeCell = cell.offset(0, colOffsets[index]);
      dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
}
```

}

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should be using an installable trigger.  Simple triggers can't perform operations that require permission from a user.

Comment: Welcome. You've provided some code - is there an actual problem with the code? What is it, and what have you done so far to resolve it. You also said "I need it to edit column A with a date anytime ANYONE enters something in a specific column." Which specific column would that be, and how does that relate to the code you included?

Comment: I think I've worked it out and it looks like iPads wont allow the script to run for some reason. When doing it with other users on a PC it works fine, its just on an iPad :(